# Why does mktime give me an hour less?

Tags: c, mktime

I would like to see if at 00:00:00 on January 1, 1970 it actually corresponds to 0 seconds, and I wrote the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int year = 1970;
    
    struct tm t = {0};
    
    t.tm_mday = 1; // January
    t.tm_year = year - 1900;
    t.tm_hour = 0;
    t.tm_isdst = -1;
    
    printf("%ld\n", mktime(&t));
    
    return 0;
}
```

it gives me a value of -3600. Where am I wrong?

PS: tested with GCC v.10.1. I tried with another compiler under another architecture and it gives me back the correct value.

Comment: Could this be related to the timezone and summer time?

Comment: Shouldn't it result in seconds from that date? Regardless of the time zone?

Comment: @RobertoRocco From that date to what?

Comment: The number-of-seconds time is defined to be UTC, but `mktime()` is defined to work with *local* time; that's the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time info you provide to `mktime()` is in *local* time, so the timezone matters even if summer time / daylight savings time does not.

You can fool your program by telling it you're in UTC:

```
$ gcc mytime.c -o mytime
$ ./mytime
28800          <-- Pacific time in the US
$ TZ=GMT0 ./mytime
0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `mktime` function takes a time in local time. Apparently, 00:00:00 at your local time was one hour before the epoch. Launch the program with `TZ` set to `UTC`.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to see if at 00:00:00 on January 1, 1970 it actually corresponds to 0 seconds, and I wrote the following:

00:00:00 on January 1, 1970 *GMT*, *UTC* corresponds to 0 seconds.

00:00:00 on January 1, 1970 [*Italia*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11736671/roberto-rocco) time corresponds to -3600 seconds.

Set timezone to UTC and then call `mktime()`.  Unfortunately C does not have a portable way to do this, so the suggested code is only illustrative.

```
setenv("TZ", "UTC", 1);
tzset();
....
mktime(&t)
```

---

`time_t` does not necessarily match `long`.  Recommend casting to a wide type.

```
// printf("%ld\n", mktime(&t));
printf("%lld\n", (long long) mktime(&t));
```

---

`t.tm_mday = 1; // January` misleads.  `.tm_mday` is the day of the month, not January.

`.tm_mon` is the months since January so the initialization to 0 matches January.

Concerns about DST apply here only if the local time was using DST in January.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers indicate, `mktime` works in your local time zone. However, many operating systems offer a related function [`timegm`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timegm.3.html) that works in UTC. This slight modification of your program prints 0, as expected, on my computer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int year = 1970;
    
    struct tm t = {0};
    
    t.tm_mday = 1; // January
    t.tm_year = year - 1900;
    t.tm_hour = 0;
    t.tm_isdst = -1;
    
    printf("%ld\n", timegm(&t));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Regrettably, this function is not standardized. You may have to define a special "feature selection macro" to get your time.h to declare it.